# ssh port forwarding with custom host name

Tags: ssh

I often do port forwarding to access remote web servers with this command:

```
ssh user@remotehost -L 1234:localhost:1234
```

So now I can enter http://localhost:1234 in my browser to access the remote host's web server. What I want to do now is use a name other than localhost. For example, is it possible to invoke ssh with some argument such that I can enter http://remotealias:1234 in my browser to access the remote web server? This is particularly useful when I'm running other services in my local machine on port 1234 at the same time (and don't want to remember many port:host tunnel mappings).

If it's not possible with the ssh command alone, I'm also interested in solutions that require editing some local configuration in my machine to make it work as described.

Comment: Have you tried to use `SOCKS5` on your browser?  `ssh -D 1234 user@remotehost`  then configure `SOCKS` in your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; You could make an IP per host on your local box

```
ip address add 122.0.0.2/32 dev eth0
ip address add 122.0.0.3/32 dev eth0
```

and edit your hosts file

```
echo "127.0.0.2 remotehost1.com" >> /etc/hosts
echo "127.0.0.3 remotehost2.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

then forward each IP to the hosts IP (direct access via domain would be broken by the hosts file change)

```
ssh user@$remotehost1_IP -L 127.0.0.2:80:localhost:1234
ssh user@$remotehost2_IP -L 127.0.0.3:80:localhost:1234
```

then use your web browser like normal

```
http://remotehost1.com
http://remotehost2.com
```

This will tunnel each remote fqdn through its own ssh tunnel, on it's own local ip.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. As far as I know, I can't specify ports in the hosts file.

Comment: I'm still confused about what this is actually doing. What is the first command doing? And, did you mean remotealias in the second command? echo "172.0.0.2 remotealias" >> /etc/hosts

Comment: I think your answer should work. I don't know much about networking, but what's the criterion to create the IP addresses in the first command `ip address add` ? My local address starts with 10. and uses a different subnet mask. Should I add a similar address with the same mask?

Comment: @MeiZhang: The first command didn't get edited, it should be `ip addr add 127.0.0.2/32 dev lo` etc. instead. You are creating additional loopback addresses, which are independent from your "local address". And your local address is on some subnet, so definitely don't use variations of that. Multiple IPv4 addresses on an interface can work, but there are situations where they can lead to trouble, because programs without binding could pick a random address out of all available ones, which is sometimes not what you want. Another option would be to add a `dummy` interface.

Comment: I see, I know this solution is a bit hacky, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
ssh user@a.company.com -L 1234:localhost:5678
```

on host b.company.com, the following happens:

- On host B, ssh starts to listen on port 1234.
- On host A, a connection is made to `localhost` (that is, host A again) on port 5678.
- Traffic on those two endpoints is forwarded over the ssh connection between A and B.

So the end result is that you can access port 5678 on host A by using port 1234 on host B.

The reason you have to type `localhost` is because host A can also be a "jump server", i.e. an entrance point into some protected network. So if you can't access host C directly from host B, but you can access host A from host B, and host C from host A, you can do

```
ssh user@a.company.com -L 1234:c.company.com:5678
```

which will establish connections between host B and A, and between host A and C, and tunnel port 5678 on host C to port 1234 on host A.

This has two consequences:

- If you are already using port 1234 on your client (host B) for other services, you can't use it for tunneling. You need to use a different port (but there's plenty to choose from).
- In your browser, you'll always connect to the local endpoint of the tunnel, i.e. `localhost`. Assigning names to remote hosts won't change this.

So no, what you want doesn't work this way.

**Edit**

In case it wasn't clear enough: You can very easily use different port numbers to you are already running local services. So assume you have hosts A, B and C which you want to reach this way, they all have services on port 80, and you are running your own web server on port 80. Then you do

```
ssh user@hosta -L 5000:localhost:80
ssh user@hostb -L 5001:localhost:80
ssh user@hostc -L 5002:localhost:80
```

and you can access them now in your browser by typing `http://localhost:5000`, `http://localhost:5001`, and `http:/localhost:5002`. And `http://localhost:80` will still access your own local server.

There's no real need for complicated constructions which involve assigning yourself lots of IP addresses, or remotealiases.

Comment: Read my answer and realize what he wants is possible if one gets creative.

Comment: @user1133275: At least in the current edit, you probably don't want to add `122.0.0.2/32` etc. to `eth0`, since you are using `127.0.0.2` on `lo` anyway... And IMHO it's much easier to just use free port numbers (I have the feeling the OP maybe didn't realize he can use different numbers for his `1234` before and after `localhost`) instead of having to deal with multiple IP addresses on loopback, which can lead to all sort of funny effects. Just because you *can* do something and it might even work under limited circumstances, doesn't mean it's a good solution. YMMV.

Comment: That take on the question turns it from a good question into a low quality question that should be deleted. So let's make stackexchange better by reducing the bloat and answer the questions that are not just a copy of the man pages.

Comment: I'm aware that I can use a different port before and after localhost. For reasons that are not important to discuss, I do want to use the same port number.

Answer (score -1):

When you establish port forwarding by ssh - you setup a bridge between port on `your_machine:port` (perspective of your machine) to `machine:port` from perspective of the machine you've made a connection to.

In other words - if you invoke command

`ssh user@remotehost -L 1234:localhost:4567`

you make an ssh connection to `remotehost` plus if you connect to port `1234` on your machine (`localhost` address for you) remote part of your ssh connection will try to make connection to `localhost` (to itself - as `localhost` on `remotehost` will point to itself) on port `4567`

Back to the meritum of question.

If you have other services on port `1234` on your machine, you can instead select another port that is free on your machine.

Comment: Start with "No" if that's what you are going to imply. Though technically "Yes" is correct for this question.